# How to find an element in the List from a specific index upto the end?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I search for an element in a List of Type starting from a specific element?

I can achieve the same using the for loop as follows:

```
bool found = false;
for(int i=counter+1;i<=lstTags.Count()-1;i++)
   {
    if (lstTags[i].PlateFormID == plateFormID)
      {
        found = true;
        break;
       }
    }
```

However, I want to know if it can be done in a more efficient way through a built-in feature like:

```
var nextItem=lstTags.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.PlateFormID==plateFormID, startIndex);
```

Comment: If by efficient you mean less code to write, then go ahead and use linq. If you want it to be faster, your loop there is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var nextItem = lstTags.Skip(startIndex).FirstOrDefault(a => a.PlateFormID == plateFormID);
```

This will filter out first `startIndex` elements and then find the first matching `PlateFormID` in the filtered enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Where((obj,index)=>yourLogic)`

**Code:**

```
var nextItem=lstTags.Where((a,index) => a.PlateFormID==plateFormID && index > startIndex ).FirstOrDefault();
```

**EX**

```
var datas = new[] { "item1","item2","item3"};
var data = datas.Where((obj,index) => index>1 ).FirstOrDefault(); //item3
```

**PS**

> - Index start with 0